# How do struts2 plugins work

Tags: java, web-applications, plugins, struts2

We are currently using the [struts2-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) plugin in our web-application.  The plugin works great but I have some questions about the internal workings of a struts2 plugin.

We added the plugin to the classpath and can use the tags defined in the taglib.  When I look in the source code of the generated page I can see that the recourse are correctly included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery-1.x.x.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
...
```

<strike>The first question is: how does our web-application know that `/struts/` points to the jquery plugin.  We did not define anything for that.</strike>
The seems to come from the `DefaultStaticContentLoader` class.  There is a method like this:

```
public boolean canHandle(String resourcePath) {
    return serveStatic && (resourcePath.startsWith("/struts/") || resourcePath.startsWith("/static/"));
}
```

The second question is that when we call an url like `/struts/` or `/struts/themes/` the application downloads a file from the plugin as an octet stream (The final result seems to be a zip files containing the css, js and image files).  Why is it doing that and is there a way to prevent that.

The second question is more important than the first.

Thanks, Tom.

EDIT: Question one was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Plugin is was provided by the S2 to extends its functionality and change the way S2 work in certain use-case.
Struts 2 plugins contain classes and configuration that extend, replace, or add to existing Struts framework functionality.Plugin should contains struts-plugin.xml file to tell S2 which is the entry point for the plugin.

So when S2 start-up, it loads the configuration in a specific manner and sequence.

1. struts-default.xml
2. struts-plugin.xml
3. struts.xml

So struts-plugin.xml being part of the plugin (jar) will be loaded by the S2 and will register with itself its presence.

for more details refer to the official documents

- [plugins](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/plugins.html)

A typical entry in struts-plugin.xml file for JQuery plugin is

```
<struts>
    <bean type="org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary" name="sj" class="com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery.views.JqueryTagLibrary" />
</struts>
```

Which tells S2 that `JqueryTagLibrary` is the entry point for plugin.The one mentioned by you about loading static content is default S2 handling mechanism until we do no provide any standard mechanism.

Struts provides a default implementation of StaticContentLoader which is `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultStaticContentLoader`. This loader will handle urls that start with "`/static/`".
For details how the static content being served by S2 from plugin and from it score jars refer to the doc

- [S2 static-content loading](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.1/docs/static-content.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This pointed me to the source of the struts url.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second question also comes from the class `DefaultStaticContentLoader`.  The `findStaticResource` method makes no difference between a folder or a file and will hence open a stream for the given url even if it is a folder.